# How to make a React Bootstrap Alert component visible?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

`<Alert/>` constructed with the code below is not visible:

```
import { Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import React from 'react';

const AlertHelloWorld = () => (
    <Alert variant="success">
        Hello World!
    </Alert>
);

export default AlertHelloWorld;
```

The code results in `opacity` set to `0`:

[image]

When I change `opacity` to `1` in the browser the alert becomes visible.

All dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.3",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
    "base-64": "0.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "es6-promise": "4.2.5",
    "express": "4.16.4",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "local-storage": "1.4.2",
    "markdown-to-jsx": "6.10.3",
    "node-sass": "4.13.1",
    "popper.js": "1.15.0",
    "prop-types": "15.6.2",
    "raf": "3.4.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "16.8.0",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "request": "2.88.0",
    "request-promise": "4.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "7.2.0"
  },
```

**What is the proper way to make the alert visible?**

Comment: This feels like a workaround, not a solution: <Alert variant={props.variant} style={{ opacity: 1 }}>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by someone's introduction of a custom `bootstrap.custom.css` with a CSS code that causes `opacity` for the `Alert` component to be set to `0`:

```
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just checked your code on my end and it seems to be working fine for me using the following dependencies:

```
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"react-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.16",
"react": "^16.9.0",
```

I can't think of a different reason why your code should not work.